# Variable from Array to datarow

Tags: .net

I'd like to use an ArrayList and get the datarow value. I've tried the following but this only gets me the literal text.

Code:

```
vString = fncX(Trim("datarow('" & vVariable & "').ToString"))
```

vString returns... `datarow('ArrayVariable').ToString`

If I put

```
vString = fncX(Trim("datarow("RealColumnName".ToString"))
```

I get the result of fncX which is great. Is there a way to do the above or should I rewrite?